# suppose $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ have degree smaller than $n$. If $a(c)=b(c)$ for $n$ values of $c$, prove $a(x)=b(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

Suppose $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ have degree smaller than $n$. If $a(c)=b(c)$ for $n$ values of $c$, prove $a(x)=b(x)$

I don't understand how there is $n$ values of $c$ but the polynomials are of degree less than $n$ and so I don't know how to go about the proof. Any hints will help!

Comment: Hint: polynomial $\,p(x)=a(x)-b(x)\,$ has degree smaller than $\,n\,$, and has $\,n\,$ roots. What do you know about the (maximum) number of roots a non-zero polynomial can have?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the $h(x)=a(x)-b(x)$ and use the algebra's fundamental theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Consider $p(x)=a(x)-b(x)$.